# Linux find with sed not work

Tags: linux, bash, sed, find

I've got a large problem. I'm trying to remove malware code from first lines of php files in my project but all the time console returns:

sed: 1: "./{PATH_TO_FILE}": invalid command code .

**My request:**

```
find . -name "*.php" -type f -exec sed -n -i '1s/.*/<?php/' {} \;
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here? :)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: How many files are there?

Comment: find . -name ".php" -type f -exec sed -n -i '1s/.*/<?php/' {} \;

Comment: Post the full comand in your question.

Comment: About 200 with php extension

Comment: Are you using any kind of version control?

Comment: I've solved a similar  problem a  couple of days ago, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049983/797495

Comment: Yes, but version in production is different than in repository

Comment: your line works for me, it just empties all found files.

Comment: Don't try to edit infected files. Replace them with clean backups

Comment: @Mithrandir: Do not combine `-n` with `-i`: it _truncates_ the input file, because `-n` suppresses all (implicit) output so that _nothing_ is written back to the input file.

Comment: I think @mklement answered you correctly above, the `-n` precludes output (without a `p` sed command, but its easier to simply remove the `-n`).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you didn't put the wildcard in ".php". it should be "*.php".

`find . -name "*.php"`

Second, you forgot to add the place-holder for the file name in the exec clause and the end of the exec clause (a semi-colon):

Third, your sed expression is invalid. If what you want to achieve is to delete the first line then '1d' should make it:

`-exec sed -n -i '1d' {} \;`

Finally, -n seems to interfere with the -i, so just remove it.

Your full command should be:

`find . -name "*.php" -type f -exec sed -i '1d' {} \;`

Comment: Good points (combining `-n` with `-i` actually _truncates_ the input file, because `-n` suppresses all (implicit) output so that _nothing_ is written back to the input file). However, the intent was to _replace_ the 1st line with `<?php`, not to _delete_ it, so it should be `sed  -i  '1s/.*/<?php/'`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot ! Finally i sloved problem using command

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name "*.php" -type f -exec sed -i '' -e "s/^<\?php.*\?>//" {} \;
```